# Magento disable products with no images via Phpmyadmin

Tags: magento

i would like to disable products with no images in `Magento 1.8`. I have tried this code:

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_int SET value = 2 
WHERE attribute_id = 4  
  AND entity_id IN (      
        SELECT entity_id 
        FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN catalog_product_entity ON catalog_product_entity.entity_id = catalog_product_entity_media_gallery.entity_id 
        WHERE catalog_product_entity_media_gallery.value is NULL
  );
```

but i have this alert:

> **Column 'entity_id' in field list is ambiguous**

How can i resolve?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your inner query on line 4 you're listing the column `entity_id`. This column name `entity_id` is not unique in your sql field list, because the column `entity_id` is in the `catalog_product_entity` table and in the `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` as well. MySQL simply doesn't know, which one of these two columns should be shown. So you have to prepend the table in your `select` area:

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_int SET value = 2 
WHERE attribute_id = 4  
  AND entity_id IN (      
        SELECT `your_table_name`.`entity_id` 
        FROM catalog_product_entity_media_gallery
        RIGHT OUTER JOIN catalog_product_entity ON catalog_product_entity.entity_id = catalog_product_entity_media_gallery.entity_id 
        WHERE catalog_product_entity_media_gallery.value is NULL
  );
```